# Story about a giant brain like thing that puts our hero in suspended animation for centuries to kill it when it needs to die

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

Hi I'm looking for the title of an animated movie probably from the 80s about a hero (a guy) and a "villain" who I recall being kind of like a giant brain/blob that could project tentacles (I think) out of itself. I don't recall the setting being Earth as in my mind it was more like alien landscape and caves.

In this story, the protagonist is befriended by humanoid cave creatures who want the brain thing destroyed. I believe it might have been enslaving them and at this point the protagonist also wants the brain destroyed and agrees to do so.

The hero acquires/is given a syringe of brain killing goo, but when he goes to inject the brain thing it stops and captures him.

Instead of killing the hero though, the brain recognizes that in the distant future, it will become ill/corrupted and will need to be euthanized. It also knows that when the times comes the sick future brain will be unwilling to kill itself. The brain's solution is to put our hero in a state of suspended animation (with the syringe) to be revived centuries later.

That comes to pass and when the hero awakens, the brain thing is in fact sick/corrupted and as predicted needs to be euthanized. Our hero proceeds to do just that (despite the brain thing now having changed it's mind about the whole plan).

This is a longshot, but I will add the the humanoids referred to the hero in all the "timelines" past, present and future of the movie as something along the lines of:

> "once was, will be our friend"

As I recall this did not make sense at the beginning of the movie, but by the end it is apparent that the (potentially enslaved) cave humanoids had predicted the events thousands of years in the future.

Comment: Adding to Clara's answer it is also titled "Light Years" in English/America.   It's been uploaded to YouTube if you care to watch it.

Comment: While I agree that this is a duplicate in the sense that we are ultimately describing the same movie. I find it interesting that few of the plot points I remembered were plot points highlighted in the other post. For example, I had completely forgotten about the robot angle, and after watching it, I had clearly forgotten about all the nudity :-P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like "[Gandahar](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095525/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)", a French animated science fiction film from 1987, based on the novel "[Les Hommes-machines contre Gandahar](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6835)" (The Machine-Men versus Gandahar) by Jean-Pierre Andrevon.

The protagonist, Sylvain, is called to investigate the invasion of the paradise of Gandahar by a robot army known as the "Men of Metal". He encounters a giant brain called "Metamorphosis" who appears to be connected to the attacks, although it claims to be innocent. According to a review on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandahar_(film)):

> Sylvain is ordered to kill Metamorphis with a special syringe. Sylvain
> returns to Metamorphis, who maintains his innocence but reveals that
> the Men of Metal come from the future via the portal Sylvain saw
> earlier. He then urges Sylvain to kill him in a thousand years, as the
> syringe would have no effect on him now. A skeptical Sylvain agrees
> and Metamorphis puts him into stasis.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: "*You were/will be my friends*":  https://youtu.be/UqTvIgtVQwg?t=3620

Comment: Is this where Futurama got the idea from (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Why_of_Fry)?